# How to scale a custom object (dae) in a scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scenekit

I am able to insert a custom object into a scene like so,

```
    NSURL *urlToColladaFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Assets.scnassets/vase-15k_saliency" withExtension:@"dae"];
    SCNSceneSource *sceneSource = [SCNSceneSource sceneSourceWithURL:urlToColladaFile options:nil];
    SCNNode *node = [sceneSource entryWithIdentifier:@"node" withClass:[SCNNode class]];
    node.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic shape:nil];
    node.physicsBody.mass = 2.0;
    node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryCube;
    node.position = position;
    node.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.1,0.1,0.1);
```

The scale makes the object look small but the geometry is still in its original size. How can I scale the geometry to make the object large/small?

Should I use the node.transform ? or  node.pivot? Any pointers are helpful please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a scale and a transform that is calculated from the scale is the same:

> The transformation is the combination of the node’s 
>   rotation, position, and scale properties. The default transformation is SCNMatrix4Identity.
>   When you set the value of this property, the node’s rotation, orientation, eulerAngles, position, and scale properties automatically change to match the new transform, and vice versa.

The pivot property has the same effect, but you should use it only if you want an offset between the nodes coordinate space and its transform.

If you want a different size of your geometry you can maybe export it in a smaller size, but this should result in the same effect.
If you want fewer polygons to be rendered for performance reasons take a look at [`SCNLevelOfDetail`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlevelofdetail)